# How to declare a class template in a structure and initialize later?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I am trying to model a tolerance stackup. I made a structure `Layer` that holds the lower limit (`tol[0]`) and upper (`tol[1]`) limit of the tolerance range. I want to generate a random value between `tol[0]` and `tol[1]` and assign it to `val`.

My implementation declares the `uniform_real_distribution` class template in the structure and initializes it in `main()`, but I'm getting errors during compilation that make me think I can't use class templates this way.

```
#include <random>

struct Layer {
    double tol[2];
    double val;
    std::string name;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution;
};

int main() 
{
    Layer block;
    block.tol[0] = .240;
    block.tol[1] = .260;

    std::default_random_engine generator;
    block.distribution(block.tol[0],block.tol[1]);
    block.val = block.distribution(generator);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following error from g++:

```
error: no match for call to '(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>) (double&, double&)'
    block.distribution(block.tol[0],block.tol1[]);
                                                ^
```

I've got quite a few `Layer` structures that I create so I was hoping to associate the distribution with struct, but I'm not sure that it is possible anymore.

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code. Please use copy/paste so we can see the real thing.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's the error I get when I compile using gcc version 4.8.1 `g++ -std=gnu++11 main.cpp -o main.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this stage, the object is already constructed, so you can do:

```
block.distribution = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(block.tol[0],block.tol[1]);
```

You can also initialize the structure directly:

```
Layer block{{.240,.260}, 0, "", std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(.240, .260)};
```

Comment: This works! I'm still confused on why this works though. Does `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>` call the constructor? I thought you called the constructor using your object name, i.e. `block.distribution(.240,.260)`

Comment: No, once the object is constructed, what you are calling is `operator()`, not the constructor.

Comment: So what is `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>` doing then?

Comment: Creating a new object that we then copy inside your structure.